# Setar nome de arquivo na dialog de um input file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Bom dia, gostaria de saber se há alguma maneira de setar um nome predefinido na dialog do `input type="file"...`. E também se há como definir o caminho em que essa dialog vai abrir. Ex.: "/Downloads/", *(gostaria que sempre abrisse nesse caminho).*

IMAGEM:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

JSFIDDLE:

http://jsfiddle.net/2s39c2y9/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Após uma consulta à documentação HTML, confirmei que não tem uma opção para definir onde o dialog vai abrir.

O que você pode definir é o tipo de arquivos que serão aceitos com accept:

> **accept**
>   If the value of the type attribute is file, this attribute indicates the types of files that the server accepts; otherwise it is ignored. The value must be a comma-separated list of unique content type specifiers:
>   A file extension starting with the STOP character (U+002E). (E.g.: ".jpg,.png,.doc")
>   A valid MIME type with no extensions
>   audio/* representing sound files HTML5
>   video/* representing video files HTML5
>   image/* representing image files HTML5

Fonte: [Documentação HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input)

Answer (score 3):

Até o momento, por razões de segurança não é possível setar a pasta em que o input file vai abrir nem o Nome de arquivo pré definido.

Isso é feito por medida de segurança para evitar que o usuário submeta algum arquivo sem perceber.

Quem precisa de coisas do tipo tem de recorrer para widgets do java, o que torna o processo mais pesado e burocrático.

Comment: E em C# conhece alguma maneira, ou não tem como mesmo?

Comment: Em C já foge dos meus conhecimentos, isso merece uma outra pergunta ;)

Comment: Sim, em C# é possível sim. Poste em outra pergunta que diremos como!